# How can a NodeJS API connect to a kerberos protected resource through JDBC

Tags: node.js, jdbc, kerberos, tibco

I have a NodeJS API which I want to access data on TIBCO DV via JDBC. The resources on TIBCO DV are protected through Active Directory (Kerberos).

The NodeJS API is running on RedHat Linux.
The Clients accessing the API will be SPA's (VueJS or React) running on Windows 10

**A Few of questions**

1. How does the user of the Single Page App Get a Kerberos Identity. (I'm using Keycloak for Authentication)
2. How does the Single Page App pass along the Kerberos identify of the user to the NodeJS API.
3. How does the NodeJS API authorize with TIBCO DV through JDBC using Kerberos